# How to Set a manual Date from Django database table to DatePicker in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django-models, django-forms

I am using django for developing my website. I want to display a date in a datepicker on a modal in html. First i picked the date value from the database. I am able to print that value in console. But I can't set it as the value of Datepicker in my modal.

Here is my code:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
$('.building-link').click(function(){
    var myHeading = $(this).data('name');
    $('#building-name').html(myHeading);
    var now = $(this).data('date');
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

     var today = (now.getFullYear() + '-' + day + '-' + month);
    $('#datepicker').val(today,0);
    $('#building-description').html($(this).data('desc'));
    //$('#building-date').html($(this).data('date'));
    //$('#building-list').html($(this).data('list'));
    //$('#building-img').src($(this).data('img'));
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col my-3">
<div class="card h-100">

<div class="card-footer">
    <small class="text-muted" style="font-weight: bold;font-size:1.4em;">{{b.name}}</small>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">Description: {{b.description}}</p>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary " type="button">Finished</button>

              <!-- Button trigger modal -->

<button type="button"  class="btn btn-outline-primary building-link"  data-date='{{b.Dates}}' data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Edit
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"> Edit Your List</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
        <br>
        <form action='/dashboard' method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}  
        
        <label class='labeler'>Do it Before:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="date" id= 'datepicker'/>
     
        <br>

      </div>
   
           

{% endblock others %}{% endblock shopping %}{% endblock work %}{% endblock travel %}{% endblock important %}{% endblock home %}
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Which datepicker library are you using. Can you give me a link.

Comment: I am just using this line of code <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="date" id= 'datepicker'/>

Comment: Is there any other datepicker library which can display the date in DD/MM/YYYY format

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```html
<input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="date" id='datepicker'/>

<button type="button"  class="btn btn-outline-primary building-link"  data-date='{{b.Dates}}' data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">
  Edit
</button>
<input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="date" id='datepicker'/>
```

Jquery

```js
$('.building-link').click(function() {
    var date = $(this).attr('data-date');
    $('#datepicker').attr('value', date);
});
```

Comment: I don't need to get today's date. Instead i can get a custom date from django database with {{b.Dates}}. I want to put this date as the value of the datePicker. I am getting the date format as: 2021-03-25 , which is - year-month-day. Can you help me to do that.

Comment: Is there a way to slice the date as day,month ,year.

Comment: What is the format of the variable {{b.Dates}}. Do you have a unix string or what?